# Rxjs - condition pipeable operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using Angular and Ngrx. I'm retrieving lots of data from my backend in many seperate calls; 2 pieces of the data in my Ngrx store state are `dashboardState.issuesState.issues` and `dashboardState.defaultAssetId`.

I have the following code to call the 'setCurrentlySelectedAsset' method:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select((state: AppState) => state.dashboard.defaultAssetId),
      tap((selectedAssetId: number) => this.setCurrentlySelectedAsset(selectedAssetId))
    ).subscribe();
```

This works, and the `setCurrentlySelectedAsset` method is called every time `state.dashboard.defaultAssetId` emits a value, great.

But I only want this method to be called IF `dashboardState.issuesState.issues` has a value (i.e. the backend request has been completed).

A possible solution could be this:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select((state: AppState) => state.dashboard),
      tap((dashboardState: State) =>
      {
        if (dashboardState.issuesState.issues && dashboardState.defaultAssetId)
        {
          this.setCurrentlySelectedAsset(dashboardState.defaultAssetId)
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

But now my `tap` will be called every time anything on `dashboardState` changes (and a lot will changes on there).

Any ideas? I've looked but haven't been able to find a pipeable operator to put inbetween the `select` and `tap`, which will then only proceed to `tap` if a certain condition, i.e. `dashboardState.issuesState.issues` having a value, is met.

Comment: You can use the [`filter` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that utilizes the [`filter` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter):

```js
this.store.pipe(
  select((state: AppState) => state.dashboard),
  filter((dashboardState: State) => dashboardState.issuesState.issues && dashboardState.defaultAssetId),
  tap((dashboardState: State) => this.setCurrentlySelectedAsset(dashboardState.defaultAssetId))
).subscribe();
```

If the predicate returns true, then the value will be emitted to `tap`, otherwise, it will not be emitted.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [filter](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter). You can pipe it between your `select` and `tap` and emits only if your condition is met.

Here is the description from the above link.

> Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those that satisfy a specified predicate.

So you could go for something like:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select((state: AppState) => state.dashboard),
      filter(dashboardState => dashboardState.issuesState.issues && dashboardState.defaultAssetId),
      tap(dashboardState => this.setCurrentlySelectedAsset(dashboardState.defaultAssetId))
    ).subscribe();
```